# How to deserialize an object correctly, if there is not all data in JSON?

Tags: ios, objective-c, serialization, architecture

Imagine that we have an application that displays articles. Let's say that every article has such fields:

```
id
title
author
text
```

So we create object to store articles:

```
@interface Article : NSObject
@property int article_id;
@property NSString *title;
@property NSString *author;
@property NSString *text;
```

If we need to display one full article - we ask the server for information about the article by it's id. Server responces with JSON (for example), and we have all fields - id,caption,title,text on that JSON. We can deserialize it and our object will have all fields.

But what if we need to get a **list** of articles from the server (display them it TableView for example)? We don't need all data for this, so server sends us JSON array with only id and caption for every article. If we deserialize that dictionaries, our object will have nil fields (author and text). Is this normal to use that object? Or we need to create some special class without that fields, and use it for news list?

Something like this:

```
@interface ArticleForTableView : NSObject
@property int article_id;
@property NSString *title;
```

What is the correct way to send selected article object to detail controller? We need to create new Article object with all fields filled (if it it correct to use ArticleForTableView), or fill fields of exiting object (if it is correct to use Article with nil fields), or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Someone else may disagree with me on this, but I don't think you really need to make another object class just to handle the different use case. As long as you are properly handling potential null values for the fields of your class then its really just up to you to make sure you have the data you need when you actually need to display it.

So if you only have id and caption in the table view, when you select a table view cell you could push your detail controller, pass the Article object you selected into detail controller and then retrieve the remaining information on demand for that article if it has not already been pulled from the server.